# AngularJS use filter with the array of ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to use filter when I've multiple ng-model with same name (array). I've the ng-model something like below. I'm trying to filter multi dimensional array of strings.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search[$index]" class="form-control"/>

<!-- val is multi dimensional String array -->
<!-- I want to use something like below -->
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in val | filter:search[]"  >
            <td ng-repeat="obj1 in obj track by $index">{{obj1}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Not sure how to apply the filter on each column.  I want to apply filter on each column.

My array contents are something like below. First line goes to the header of the table. This is just a CSV file converted to multidimensional array.

```
[
    [
        "SKU",
        "OfferTermCode",
        "RateCode"
    ],
    [
       "G8AXBRPMUXJ7CWNZ",
       "JRTCKXETXF",
       "G8AXBRPMUXJ7CWNZ.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y"
    ],
    [
       "G8AXBRPMUXJ7CWNZ",
       "JRTCKXETXF",
       "G8AXBRPMUXJ7CWNZ.JRTCKXETXF.6YNURZBX9Y"
    ]
]
```

My Header is like this. Followed by search boxes on each column
[image]

Comment: Provide extra details & code. didn't get you

Comment: Do you want individual filters for each column?

Comment: Why don't you use you filter in expression `{{ }}`

Comment: @Louie Almeda : Yes the filter is on individual column on the table header.

Comment: @srinannapa ok, can you provide the structure of your array?

Comment: @Louie Almeda : Updated the question

Comment: @srinannapa, what is `search[]`, do you want to pass an array or an object in the array `search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the **ng-table** library here http://ng-table.com/#/,
you can apply realtime filters and see the matching results on the table.
You can find ready working examples and attach to your main code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you have let's say a multi-dimensional array of let's say numbers. and you want to filter them all as currency when you show them on your page.

You could apply the filter to each cell when you iterate over it.

meaning let's assume you have an array of 1 dimension and you use ng-repeat on it like

```
<tr ng-repeat="cell in Array">
    <td>{{ cell | currency }}</td>
</tr>
```

So you applied the filter when you display the cell, and not apply filter on the whole array beforehand.

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: this is just assuming you have a very simple array for example
[10, 20, 13, 7]